# Generating df with hours from a specified date and lost hours

Tags: r, datetime

The following works fine, however today I found that one hour is missing from the list. How to explain this and how to avoid similar cases?

```
df.ref <- data.frame(Data = seq(as.POSIXct("2020-11-25 18:00:00"), now(), by = "hour"))
```

[image]

Date is missing 2023-03-26 02:00:00

This is due to the time change from winter to summer time. However, the date of the change is movable. I check the completeness of hourly data in a day by counting observations. On the days when the time changes, there are 23 hours/observations and my mechanism considers these days as incomplete.

EDIT:
The expected result is a new column with the values 0 or 1. 0 when there are less than 24 hours (observations) in a given day. 1 when there are 24 hours in a day (observations) or 23 hours (observations), but this is the day in which the time change occurred.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're calling lubridate::now() and with this I can't duplicate your problem. You *might* try: Sys.time() instead of now() and see if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could derive the desired flag for the given dataset by the below `dplyr` solution. We derive the indicator, whether it is a date of a `DST` change using `lubridate::dst()`.

```
df.ref <- data.frame(Data = seq(as.POSIXct("2020-11-25 18:00:00"), now(), by = "hour"))

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df.ref |>
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Data, tz = "")) |> 
  mutate(DSTChange = dst(as.character(Date)) != lead(dst(as.character(Date)))) |>
  mutate(IsDSTChangeDate = any(DSTChange),
         NumEntries = n(), .by = Date) |> 
  mutate(Flag = ifelse(NumEntries == 24 | IsDSTChangeDate == TRUE, 1, 0)) |> 
  select(-c(Date, DSTChange, IsDSTChangeDate, NumEntries))
```

E.g. using `df.ref` as given in the question, `head()` for `Flag == 0` would give as expected the following entries:

```
                 Data Flag
1 2020-11-25 18:00:00    0
2 2020-11-25 19:00:00    0
3 2020-11-25 20:00:00    0
4 2020-11-25 21:00:00    0
5 2020-11-25 22:00:00    0
6 2020-11-25 23:00:00    0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ever end with missing date time rows for whatever reason, this solution would fill in the missing between the oldest and newest time range. This uses the `complete` function

```
datez <- c('2023-03-25 23:00:00','2023-03-26 00:00:00','2023-03-26 01:00:00','2023-03-26 03:00:00'
        ,'2023-03-26 04:00:00','2023-03-26 05:00:00','2023-03-26 06:00:00')

df <- data.frame(datez)

df$datez <- as.POSIXct(df$datez,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',tz='CST6CDT')

df <- complete(df,datez = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXlt(min(datez)),as.POSIXlt(max(datez)),by="hour"))
```